# openui5 can't find <template:repeat> in xml view

Tags: xml, xml-namespaces, sapui5

According to:[sap documentation: repeat](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/512e545ba66f4214ba0de1eb56f319e1.html) I should be able to use a repeat tag to loop over my data.
I added the template namespace `xmlns:template="http://schemas.sap.com/sapui5/extension/sap.ui.core.template/1"` but when I try to run my code it gives the following error:

> *Uncaught Error: failed to load 'http://schemas/sap/com/openui5/extension/sap/ui/core/template/1/repeat.js' from webjars/openui5/1.42.6/*

I can't change my openui5 version.
I work in Eclipse with an openui5 front-end and a Java services back-end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error looks like UI5 is trying to load the pre-processor directives as if they were controls. Because controls are not yet loaded during pre-processing, I guess that this happens during view control tree instantiation. This in turn indicates that the template instructions were still present in the XML view at the moment when the control tree was built.

Are you sure you actually have "activated" XML pre-processing before instantiating your view? Check out the XML pre-processing [documentation](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/5ee619fc1370463ea674ee04b65ed83b.html) (more specifically, the "calling the preprocessor" example).

Actually, now that I am reading your question again, I think you want to use XML pre-processing instructions for building the UI **based on your data**.  This should not be the case, you should use XML pre-processing / templateing only for building the views **based on your meta-data** (i.e. only once, the first time the view is shown).

For adapting your views based on your data, you should use [data binding](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/68b9644a253741e8a4b9e4279a35c247.html) instead. More specifically, you should use [aggregation binding](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/91f057786f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070.html) to emulate a loop.

Comment: I opened the webjar file and the "repeat.js" file isn't in there. I checked if it was added in a later version but it should be in this already.

Comment: And thanks for the coding guidelines, I'm fairly new to UI5 so I don't know a lot of this kind of stuff. I'll read the information you linked and try to find a solution for my problem in it.

Comment: That file never existed and will never exist. As I have said, UI5 makes that request because it thinks that "repeat" is a control. It is not a control; it is a pre-processing instruction. UI5 is fundamentally different than e.g. Angular: you do not have a "loop" for creating controls for each line of an data array. The repeat instruction that you have used can be used only in XML pre-processing (which is a very advanced topic in UI5; you should not need it for simple scenarios).